# What is inside the Schwarzschild radius of the Sun?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mass, event-horizon

According to https://www.britannica.com/science/Schwarzschild-radius, the Schwarzschild radius for a black hole with the mass of the Sun is about 2 miles. My question is what is inside of it? Is whatever is inside of it similar to what surrounds it? Can particles escape? Or does the whole sun have to collapse into it for particles to be trapped inside of it?

Comment: Search term: [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not relevant to the physics of the sun. Nothing happens there.

You can construct an exact solution to general relativity describing an idealized star (spherically symmetric, nonrotating, surrounded by vacuum). You do this by combining an interior solution describing the matter with an exterior solution describing the vacuum around it. The vacuum part of the solution is the Schwarzschild geometry.

If you extend the Schwarzschild geometry inward to the center, strange things happen at the Schwarzschild radius. But in the stellar model, that part of the solution isn't used; a different solution to general relativity applies there. The odd behavior of the vacuum solution would only be relevant if the star collapsed to a size comparable to that radius, which never happens to solar-mass stars.

Comment: So what is inside of the Schwarzschild radius of the sun? Vacuum or particles?

Comment: @CraigFeinstein Particles.

Comment: @CraigFeinstein I do not really understand this - the Schwarzschild radius is a radius where - if you go below it - (that is, less than) - then it becomes a black hole, but asking what the "Schwarzschild radius of the sun" is - is not really, how to put it - the sun isn't a black hole (as far as my knowledge goes, it's still a sun since we have, *well the sunlight* and - the above answer benrg posted is really good) so right now - what is inside the Schwarzschild radius of the sun is probably undefineable since it hasn't "happened" yet (if I can put it this way). 
*simplified speaking here*.

Comment: @WilliamMartens you bring up the issue that puzzled me when I wrote this question (and still puzzles me). Is extra space created by the collapse of a star?

Comment: @CraigFeinstein I am both: not sure what you exactly mean by "extra" "space" that is, and being "created" by the collapse of a star, if you mean gravitational waves, or space like itself, (..) also I do not study Physics so I am **really not in place to answer** - to give my thought of it; I do not think "space is *destroyed*  nor *created*" I *think* it is sort of it just moves or "behaves" (not really disappear or appears)
**I can be wrong though!** really, I suggest asking that question if it's not off topic;

Comment: @CraigFeinstein to simplify (And short-ify) what I meant with the first above comment: I mean as in - it's like asking what happened at date x.y.z but the date x.y.z hasn't happened yet; so - the Schwarzschild radius of the sun is not really a question because it hasn't happened yet. it's - undefined, at the moment 8) put

Answer (score 0):

The schwarzschild radius defines the location of the event horizon that surrounds a black hole. Note that there *is* no black hole inside the sun because the density of the material in the sun's core is insufficient to create one.

But if there were, the rest of the sun would fall into it quickly and from our point of view all that matter would get squashed onto the event horizon and flattened to zero thickness.

As stated in your question, for that to happen, the mass of the entire sun would need to be compressed down into a sphere 2 km across. This will never occur in the sun's lifetime.